# How with pint to remove empty line in class declaration?

Tags: laravel, pint

Which property have I to set from
https://github.com/laravel/pint/blob/main/resources/presets/laravel.php
rules to remove empty line in class declaration :

```
class Classname 
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $currentLocate = 'ua';

    /** @var UserQuizzesHistory Collection */
    protected $userQuizzesHistoriesForReview;
```

between 2 lines ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I think you want to `class_attributes_separation` [rule](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/rules/class_notation/class_attributes_separation.rst).

If you just want the class properties to have no lines between them then the configuration would look something like this:

```php
'class_attributes_separation' => [
    'elements' => [
        'property' => 'none',
    ]
]
```

If you want to preserve the Laravel Pint configuration for the other class attributes then it would look like this:

```php
'class_attributes_separation' => [
    'elements' => [
        'const' => 'one',
        'method' => 'one',
        'property' => 'none',
        'trait_import' => 'none',
    ],
],
```